# How to get apache service status by python

Tags: linux, python-2.7

In my python code I have an if condition that checks if apache2 is running then it does stop it else does nothing.
I searched a lot but couldn't find a working python2.7 command to get Apache2 service status in Linux Debian 8.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! What code have you tried so far? This way we can help you get to where you need to go.

Comment: @Zack Tarr you are so kind. I got to resolve it by my own.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it by my own.

```
apache_status = subprocess.check_output("ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep apache2 | wc -l", shell = True)
        if  int(apache_status[0:1]) != 0:
            subprocess.call("service apache2 stop".split())
```